# CKEditor: LocationMap not working

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have successfully installed CKEditor. Now I am trying to add [locationmap plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/locationmap).

**First:** I tried to add it like it says.

> config.locationMapPath = 'path';

I also added this with the path of the googlemap.html however when I click on the icon

[image]

**Second:** I tried setting the global base path variable because my idea is that this is a path issue.

> window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "http://www.partymag.org/ckeditor/";

However when I set the basepath it show this error on the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ltr' of undefined

I searched oline for solution and none of them solved this. Here is what I have tried:

1. **Clearing the cache**, I have done this multiple times, tried different browsers, heck I even uploaded my source to server and tried on different computers but same error.
2. **Setting the language**, I seen this solution couple of times online. I added the line

> config.language = 'en'

I have downloaded the latest ckeditor without having a previous version. I tried deleting ckeditor files and re-adding them. I probably tried a lot of things. Things I don't remember. But I have been stuck with this for two days. Please any suggestion might help.

Regards.